# Why does this code not work in IE7?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7

Code: 
http://www.webdevout.net/test?0U

Demo:
http://www.webdevout.net/test?0U&raw

This works in most modern browsers (Safari, Chrome, Firefox, IE8/9), but doesn't work in IE7: what gives? I basically want to let the content dictate the size of the container, and I want the header to block display and take up the fill width of the container....

So if you notice, the box on the left has content, and the green box stretches to accommodate it... make sense?

I'm doing text-indent because the green boxes have text in them and are being replaced with a background-image sprite... so that part needs to stay.

Comment: There are things that don't work in old IE versions. That why this code does not work in IE7. And you should handle it and change something in your code.

Comment: How do you want it to work? On my machine, there's a difference between the browsers you mention. (In the rightmost div, there is a small green bar with IE 8, a larger one with Chromium 16, and nothing with Firefox 10.) What is it supposed to display?

Comment: The left box has content... in all browsers other than IE7, the green bar stretches to accommodate. They all generally work the same way. Ignore the right box: all I was trying to demonstrate was the fact that the green box doesn't stretch all the way.

Answer (score 0):

Try to style the header with `position:absolute` and because it is going to be a background image, you can add `z-index:999` to the text.

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the height declaration in your header style. If you want to change the height of the box change your font-size property.